# Batch file find string that contains substring and assign to variable

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that will look in a file for a string and replace it with new value.

for ex.

test.txt contains several lines that will contain the following text where YYYYMMDD can be different:

```
"location":"/test/update_20130723/update_20130723.txt"
"/test/update_20130723/update_20130724.txt",
"/test/update_20130723/update_20130725.txt"
```

I would like the batch file to update test.txt where "update_*" with "update_20130726"

here is my test.bat:

```
set newFilename="/test/update_20130726/update_20130726.txt"

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (test.txt) do (
set str=%%a
set str=!str:"update_*/update_*.txt"=%newFilename%!
echo !str!>> newfile
)
```

When i try to run this code, nothing gets updated test.txt.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To add a command using repl:

repl.bat can be found here too - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

```
type "test.txt" | repl "(update_........)" "update_20130726" m >"file.txt"
```

Comment: can repl.bat be used to find all "NUL" values (where "NUL" has hex value of 00) and replace with empty space? I tried type "test.txt" | repl "00" "" m x \xnn >update_test.txt and doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: `type "test.txt" | repl "\x00" "" mx >"update_test.txt"`  <-- this should work.